# Clueless - Exceeding execution time

Tags: google-apps-script

I took this code from a sheet that was provided to me to use, but it's inefficient and times out before completing. I'm trying HARD to re-write it in a super simple format to get it to complete within the time limit. This is what I started with:

```
    function addTo() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
// Style 1
  // Size 2
  var num1 = ss.getRange("AL2").getValue();
  var num2 = ss.getRange("O2").getValue();
  ss.getRange("O2").setValue(num1+num2);
  ss.getRange("AL2").clearContent();
  // Size 4  
  var num1 = ss.getRange("AM2").getValue();
  var num2 = ss.getRange("P2").getValue();
  ss.getRange("P2").setValue(num1+num2);
  ss.getRange("AM2").clearContent();
```

Then repeat that about 200 times. Someone suggested processing as a range instead. That makes sense and should result in a faster process. But I'm having trouble writing it. This is what I have so far (it's not working though):

```
function addallatOnce() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var startrange = ss.getRange("Inventory Received!B2:U48");
  var addrange =  ss.getRange("Inventory Received!Y2:AR48");
  var complete = startrange+addrange
  ss.getRange("Inventory Received!B50:U96").setValues(complete);
}
```

I don't usually write code, I can understand what I'm reading, but I don't know anything about writing it. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show us the entire addTo function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With Google Script**

Google has some [excellent documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) on optimizing code. In this case you can perform batch operations using arrays. First feed the spreadsheet data into the arrays using the getValues() function on the ranges. Note that getValues() returns a 2D array of the values within the range. Loop through all the values and add them together, value by value. Then assign the desired range the value of the complete array.

```js
function addallatOnce() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var startrange = ss.getRange("Inventory Received!B2:U48").getValues();
  var addrange =  ss.getRange("Inventory Received!Y2:AR48").getValues();
  var complete = addrange;
  var row = 0;
  var col = 0;
  for (row = 0; row < complete.length; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < complete[0].length; col++) {
      complete[row][col] = addrange[row][col] + startrange[row][col];
    }
  }
  ss.getRange("Inventory Received!B50:U96").setValues(complete);
}
```

**Without Google Script**

Put the following formula in cell B50 of Inventory Received:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(B2:U48+Y2:AR48)
```

See documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en).